# Do iPhones get sent to home screen after long periods of inactivity?

Tags: ios, iphone, lockscreen, homescreen

Usually, if one locks an iPhone while on a certain app, then unlocks it, that same app will be on the screen.

I've heard that after long periods of inactivity, (in the locked screen state), when the phone unlocks it doesn't show the app that is currently open, rather sends it to the background and goes to the home screen.

Is this true?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question but more about what iOS may or may not do.

Comment: Well it affects my app.... I need my app to stay "inactive" while the screen is locked and not be sent to the background.

Comment: If there are no memory warnings and nothing else to take up memory then  no, your app will not be terminated. Can you guarantee anything on that? No. What does your app do that you want to keep it this way? Also, if the user get a notification that pens another app then your app may be terminated due to memory pressure.

Answer (score 1):

The App may be terminated in the background, but will be reopened if the user unlocks his device. This does not happen to Apps that play audio.

You may want to check about [background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).